# Smarty include in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, include, smarty

I have a smarty template for a form in which I want to dynamically include other templates. The names of these template files are contained in an array. I want to loop through this array and for every item include the matching file.

```
{foreach from=$content->getForm() key=key item=element}
    {include file="templates/form/$element.tpl"}
{/foreach}
```

However, when I try to execute this code, I get a 500 error, which means this code does not work. When I comment out the include, everything works, and even when I just print the combined location, everything works.

```
templates/form/name.tpl 
templates/form/address.tpl 
templates/form/contact.tpl 
templates/form/message.tpl
```

I even tried including the a static location in the foreach, which also works. Does anyone know what can be the problem and how I can fix it?

Thanks for regarding my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try alternative syntax:

```
{include file="templates/form/{$element}.tpl"}
```